PTR record for a WAF
I have a website behind a WAF. The WAF host is used for mail-sending activity.
Our team informed me that the host IP address does not have a PTR record configured.  I understand that it is a recommended  practice to have a PTR record configured.

Will a PTR record have a negative effect if on the domain if the record does not belong to me, since the IP address is technically the WAF?

Do WAF typically have a static or dynamic IP address? I don't want to run into mismatch issues between A and PTR records.


The WAF we utilize is Imperva.

If I understand you correctly, your WAF acts as a relayhost, e.g. it runs a service (SMTP or whatever) to receive your mails and then it delivers them further using SMTP. Do you administer this feature of WAF, or is it provided as a service?

Yup, that is exactly what is happening. This is provided as a service and the IP address provided by the WAF is shared.


I understand that it is a recommended practice to have a PTR record configured.

No. It's good practice on internet facing relays but NOT for hosts sitting behind a relay. Indeed, it's rather bad practice to implement PTR records for satellite systems; it creates an unnecessary dependency on network architecture and DNS (SMTP AUTH, client certs, and VPNs provide the required functionality without the external dependencies in such a scenario). Perhaps whomever you spoke to misunderstood what you were describing.

Do WAF typically have a static or dynamic IP address?

We are talking about the SMTP server NOT the WAF here. It should not matter unless someone has been silly enough to apply IP based authentication on an internal host.

Thanks a lot for your input here, it was really simple to follow along. Appreciate it!

If you're going to use your "WAF" as a relayhost (I wonder why it's called "web application firewall" then, because SMTP is not "web" anymore), it should be configured as a proper SMTP relayhost. In particular, it must have a PTR configured. But if it's given to you as a service ready to be used, you shouldn't bother about it; the burden of setting the SMTP services on the relayhost lies on system administrators of the relayhost.
Look, I am just explaining expectations from a email service provider. The fact they are primarily WAF service provider doesn't matter; as long as they assume email relay role, they must comply with certain rules.
Your email domain name and the host name of their relayhost server (which is specified in the PTR record) are totally different and unrelated things. Since the IP is shared (I believe, with other customers), they should use some "neutral" name under their control. So it shouldn't affect your domain. That PTR should be kept consistent not only with A record, but also with the HELO name their SMTP server will use (e.g. it will appear not only in DNS, but also in their server configuration).
For you to integrate properly, as email relay service owners, they should:

tell you the set of the IP addresses they use to send out mail for you to include into your domain's SPF policy (should you have one);
be able to provide you with their DKIM key (should you want to use a restrictive DMARC policy for your domain), and ask you about the selector name under which you published their DKIM key in your domain's DNS.

This, hopefully, answers your point 1.

Point 2 is about understanding terminology. A "static address" is not a type of an address, but a method of getting it on the end system, and it only matters to that system admins.
No remote has any means to determine exactly how an IP was configured on a server (e.g. was it DHCP, or IPIP, or written into a server configuration files a.k.a. "static", or calculated some other way, like server farm, where it could assume a sequential number of a server in a farm). For that reason, there are no "true" checks for the remote's address being static, and there could be no such requirement.
All the checks "of that kind" that exist rely on address lists voluntarily published by address owners. They promise that certain addresses out of their pools are considered "static" and their assignment to their systems or customers won't change often, while others are considered "dynamic", so they reserve the ability to reassign them to different customers often. But nobody is required to publish detailed policies.
For the rest of the world, a remote system having a "static IP" could mean "whenever I see the address, I know that it's the same system that I seen yesterday" and the correspondence is long-term (like year).
As long as this condition is satisfied, the IP can be safely used to send mail for as many domains as they want.

That's a long read, thanks for taking the time for typing it out!
You are absolutely spot on by the IP address being shared with other customers. We do also have SPF and DMARC configured for the domain.
I understand that a static IP address is simply a terminology or a name given to an IP address (or system) saying that this IP is going to stay with me (the system) and will not be changing anytime soon.
I don't usually deal with system configurations but i saw this popup in an email chain and got curious.
